# Error Occur while debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am developing  **WinForm** application using ***vb.net with Ms-Access database engine.***
The **either of the following error message** displays while debugging. It didn't happen before, this is the first time, these new errors have occurred. And it displays time to time.

> Error while trying to run project: The object has been rundown by the stub manager while there are external clients.

**OR**

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
>   The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Comment: Could it be that you were also opening the database from access at that time?